# Prompt with custom answers

Tags: c#, botframework

How can I set up a prompt with my own answers?

Currently I have this code:

```
await context.PostAsync(this._questionGroups[0].Questions[_currentQuestion].Text);
```

but I would like to do something like:

```
var question = this._questionGroups[0].Questions[_currentQuestion];
var questionText = question.Text;
var answers = question.Answers;

PromptDialog.Choice(context, StepTwoQuestionsAsync, answers, questionText);
```

But it doesn't seen to work.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of messing around and using their (crap) documentation, I managed to solve this:

```
private async Task AskQuestion(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
{

    // Get our activity
    var activity = await result;

    // Get our question and answers
    var question = this._questionGroups[_currentStep].Questions[_currentQuestion];
    var questionText = question.Text;
    var answers = question.Answers.Select(m => m.Text).ToList();
    var options = new PromptOptions<string>(questionText, options: answers);

    // Ask our question
    Choice<string>(context, GetAnswer, options);
}

private async Task GetAnswer(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
{

    // Ask our question
    await context.PostAsync("Does this work?");

    // If our category is a camera, forward to our QuestionDialog
    await context.Forward(new StepTwoDialog(), ResumeAfter, new Activity { Text = await result }, CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Easy enough to sort out.

Answer (score 0):

Search abou bots and QnA, its most properly for what you looking for...